# Memory leak in assignment operator for binary search tree

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

So I can't seem to find out why I'm leaking memory, can anyone help? I've implemented a binary search tree with `operator=:`

```
BinTree& BinTree::operator=(const BinTree &other)
{
    if (other.root == NULL)
        root = NULL;
    else
    {
        copyHelper(root, other.root);
    }
    return *this;

}
```

copyHelper:

```
void BinTree::copyHelper(Node *&current, const Node *other)
{
    if (other == NULL)
        current = NULL;
    else
    {
        current = new Node;
        current->data = other->data;
        copyHelper(current->left, other->left);
        copyHelper(current->right, other->right);
    }   
}
```

I understand that `current = new Node;` is where the leak is happening, but my program crashes if I try to do `delete current;` before that line.

Here is my destructor:

```
BinTree::~BinTree()
{
    destroyRecursive(root);
}

void BinTree::destroyRecursive(Node *node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        destroyRecursive(node->left);
        destroyRecursive(node->right);
        delete node;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what does your `Node` destructor look like? NB You need to deep-copy `data` as well, unclear whether that's happening.

Comment: You don't show a single `delete`, so how is anyone supposed to comment on potential leaks?

Comment: @EJP I added the destructor

Comment: @EJP okay, but Im still leaking memory

Comment: So you added the destructor, but are you calling it? Did you add a `delete` anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Since you use raw pointers you must delete allocated memory manually. You leak memory when you set `current` to `NULL`

```
void BinTree::copyHelper(Node *&current, const Node *other)
{
    if (other == NULL)
    {
        delete current;    // w/o this line next
        current = NULL;    // will cause memory leak (if not managed somewhere else)
    }
    else
    {
        current = new Node;
        current->data = other->data;
        copyHelper(current->left, other->left);
        copyHelper(current->right, other->right);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Pls, make [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is impossible to find reason from posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Poor code structure. C++ gives you every facility for doing this, yet you're taking little or no advantage of it. You need to delete the *root* of the current tree, *in the operator function,* and then *copy-construct* the new nodes; and you need to fix your destructors.

1. The recursive copy helper should be a copy constructor in the Node class:

   ```
    Node::Node(const Node &other) : left(0), right(0)
    {
        this->data = other.data; // This must be a deep copy
        if (other.left)
            this->left = new Node(other.left);
        if (other.right)
            this->right = new Node(other.right);
    }
   ```
2. This is called by the `BinTree` assignment operator:

   ```
    BinTree& BinTree::operator=(const BinTree &other)
    {
        delete root;
        this->root = 0;
        if (other.root)
            this->root = new Node(other.root);
        return *this;
    }
   ```
3. You don't need the recursive destroy method. All you need in the `BinTree` destructor is `delete root;`, and a destructor for `Node`:

   ```
    Node::~Node()
    {
        delete left;
        delete right;
    }
   ```
4. The copying of `data` must be a deep copy. For example, if it's a C string, use `strdup(),` and `free()` it in the destructor for `Node`. If it's a class, that class must have an assignment operator.
5. As a matter of fact you don't need two classes. Every node is a tree. So you just need a `BinTree` class.

Comment: Node must be a struct for this exercise, what can I do from there??

Comment: Doesn't make any difference, it can still have operators and constructors and destructors. Strange requirement.